# Search for lyrics to a song/bhajan by ravidas/taidas

Tags: prahlada

Hi guys I need to track down the lyrics to a old bhajn/song that went like " saach batawo prahlada kaun gun tunneh" I think.it was be the poet ravidas
/raidas. If any has a copy or knows which book I can find it. Would.be much appreciated

Comment: You may have some more luck if you can spell the words out in Devanagari script in your post- that way the pronunciation will be clear.